# 3 monitors, 2 X screens, Twinview not working as expected

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors

I have 3 monitors on 2 graphics cards (both nvidia)

to get all 3 working i set 2 as twinview and one to have its own x screen.

but when i do this, the twinview screens (which previously worked like 2 seperate screens) now work as one, ie a maximised window is across both screens

How can i get the twinview to work as 2 seperate screens again?

Comment: Can you post your config?

Comment: What drivers are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tutorial for setting up a Linux machine with 3 monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/98242/tutorial-for-setting-up-a-linux-machine-with-3-monitors)

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't fully answer you, but I manage to get my three screens working with nvidia using Xinerama. Have a look at my solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/98242/tutorial-for-setting-up-a-linux-machine-with-3-monitors/122651#122651). the windows maximise as expected using openbox (ie: only one monitor), and you don't mess around with multiple screens.